# Is it possible to have biometric_storage to a centralized database where it can store multiple Users Fingureprints flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-biometric-prompt

I have a flutter app with biometric authentication, currently only works with local authentication but I wanted to have all biometric information on a centralized place eg FireStore, or any other third-party storage where all devices will be submitting their fingerprints for verification. How can I achieve that as android seems to only allow local authentication using biometric?

Comment: You can't, unless you use some external fingerprint reader that allows extraction of the fingerprint data. Android does not give apps access to any such data from the internal fingerprint reader.

Comment: Hi I have the same case like yours, did you find any solution for your question ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get access to any sort of biometric data from device. but you can do it differently.

For each user:

-> define unique id such as  access token/username anything that is unique to user.

-> get the user enrolled for biometric authentication

-> on first time authentication, encrypt the unique id and post to the server & do whatever you wish to do. you can later use it for user authentication

-> in subsequent biometric authentication, fetch the previously stored encrypted id from server and decrypt it and authenticate against the user entered credentials.

Comment: I have 10 POSs of which users are using for registration, the problem is that every users biometric data is stored on a separate POS. However, I want to centralize it so that all POSs should verify using the server

Comment: Check with POS manufactures if they have any  libs/SDKs to extract the biometric data from their POS.